# How to automatically escape special characters in a thymeleaf pathvariable?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, path-variables

I am sending a string pathvariable from a thymeleaf href template to a Spring-boot controller but if a URL is contained in this string, its slash characters "//" get interpreted as a part of the href URL. Is there a way how to get these symbols automatically escaped?

thymeleaf

```
<a th:href="@{/displayComments/{comments}(comments=${excerpt.comments})}">Comments</a>
```

where

```
comments=${excerpt.comments} = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv=j1wgaFJ0750'
```

and the URL is reported with `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)`

```
http://localhost:8080/displayComments/https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv=j1wgaFJ0750
```

Comment: Have you seen https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-utility-methods-for-uri-url ?

Comment: Seems like something like this should work: `th:href="@{/displayComments/{comments}(comments=${#uris.escapePathSegment(excerpt.comments)})}"` (untested)

Comment: I recommend using this: `th:href="@{/displayComments/{comments}(comments=${#uris.escapePathSegment(excerpt.comments, 'UTF-8')})}"` - it explicitly includes the encoding as `UTF-8`, so you can avoid being tripped up by unexpected default encodings.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe hey, thank you ... this helped

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf will automatically URL encode query parameters (content following a `?`).

But here you want to URL encode a URL path segment - so you need to explicitly handle that:

```
th:href="@{/displayComments/{comments}(comments=${#uris.escapePathSegment(excerpt.comments, 'UTF-8')})}"
```

I recommend using the version of the function which takes an encoding parameter, so you can explicitly use `UTF-8` and avoid being tripped up by unexpected default encodings.